# Can I use `intent.setClassName()` to limit a broadcast sending?

Tags: android, security, android-intent

I was sending a broadcast like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(com.test.CHANGE_MESSAGE_COUNT);
intent.putExtra("count", 1);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But someone says I'm having some security problem, and I should use `intent.setClassName`, so that my intent can not be hijacked.

So I modified my code, added a line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(com.test.CHANGE_MESSAGE_COUNT);
intent.setClassName(context, "NotExistingClass");
intent.putExtra("count", 1);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I found that even I set a class name not ever exist, I can still recieve the broadcast, which means my intent can still be hijacked.

So I wonder if there is something wrong with my code or that `setClassName` just can be used in starting a activity but not in sending a broadcast?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Broadcast Security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795987/android-broadcast-security)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Intent.setPackage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29) which will limit the app that can receive the broadcast to having that package name.

[EDIT] Also consider using a [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) if you're broadcasting in the same process that your receiver resides in

Comment: I tried `intent.setPackage("dsafsfsdaf")`, but I still received the broadcast, seems not working?

Comment: I'm not sure what happens if you call setPackage() with an invalid package that doesn't exist. Have you tried with a real package name?

Comment: Right package works right, but wrong package still works, it should be this setting not working.

Comment: But `LocalBroadcastManager` is good, this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you use an invalid package, the system presumably doesn't know who to deliver it to so probably just makes an assumption that as a best effort it should send it to everyone

Answer (score 0):

You could use LocalBroadcastManager to resolve this issue. I list descpritons in google develop docs about this class: 
Helper to register for and send broadcasts of Intents to local objects within your process. You know that the data you are broadcasting won't leave your app, so don't need to worry about leaking private data.
It is not possible for other applications to send these broadcasts to your app, so you don't need to worry about having security holes they can exploit.
It is more efficient than sending a global broadcast through the system.