# Make a service in android reply when Sensor changed

Tags: android

I would like to make an application which has an Activity A and Service B. In B, I make a function in which I process sensor data  to make a new data object C (i.e extract apply FFT, classify ...) when sensor had changed. Afterward, object C will be sent to activity automatically.

I knew that in Android we have [Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). Within bound service, from activity, we can send message (or communicate with) to service and then service responds. It is probably some kinds of control because service can not itself send message to activity.

In this situation, I am finding out a desired way, could you please give me some advices? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can send messages from service to activity with [Broadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Does it help you?

Comment: I want a specific activity can receive, because of security matters. I am reading about broadcast, but could you please tell me broadcast is satisfied?

Comment: About security you can watch [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795987/android-broadcast-security).